# How to save android canvas as svg?

Tags: android, canvas, svg

Is there any possible way to save the android canvas as svg. I know how to save it as png/jpeg. Im currently saving it as jpeg. Here is the code that I use now for saving.

```
            canvas.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);
            canvas.setDrawingCacheQuality(View.DRAWING_CACHE_QUALITY_HIGH);
            Bitmap bitmap = canvas.getDrawingCache();
            String path = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath();
            File file = new File(path+"/image.jpg");
            FileOutputStream ostream;
            try {
                file.createNewFile();
                ostream = new FileOutputStream(file);
                bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, ostream);
                ostream.flush();
                ostream.close();
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "image saved", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "error", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
```

I want the canvas to be saved as svg?

Comment: Do you even know what a SVG is? It's a vectorial file. Meaning that every line, curve, path is expressed in therms of coordinates (position at x,y, move to x1,y1, make a circle which has center in x3,y3 and has a radius of n pixels, ...). Android doesn't support SVG files natively. Even though they are xml based. You will need a 3rd party library to **read** a SVG. But there's nothing yet to convert from **bitmap** to **vectorial**, AFAIK.

Answer (score 1):

It is not clear whether you mean you want to save a Bitmap as an SVG, or you want to save a Canvas as an SVG.  They are not necessarily the same things.  From your sample code, it sounds like you mean to save a Bitmap.

**Saving a bitmap**

As Der Gollum said, saving a bitmap as an SVG gives you nothing.  SVG is a vector format. You could put the bitmap image in an SVG, like the following example (assuming a 640x480 image).  SVG files are just XML, so you could generate something like the following:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE svg PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD SVG 1.1//EN" "http://www.w3.org/Graphics/SVG/1.1/DTD/svg11.dtd">
<svg version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
     xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"
     width="640px" height="480px">
  <image width="640" height="480"
         xlink:href="data:image/jpeg;base64,...base64 encoded image data here..."/>
</svg>
```

You have an SVG file, but it's still just a bitmap.  It's the same as having a JPEG image in a PDF file.

It is possible to use tools to trace a bitmap and generate vector images.  But that is a hard problem, and the tools that do it (like "potrace") don't usually produce results that can be used without manual tweaking.

**Saving a Canvas**

The other thing you might be referring to is recording Canvas 2D drawing commands (such as `Canvas.drawRect()` for example) and producing an SVG file from that.  That is technically possible, but I am not aware of any tool or library that exists that does that.

Comment: Thank you @paul. I basically wnated to save the canvas as svg!. I added the the sample code just to show how I am doing it now. I know saving canvas as bitmap and saving canvas as svg is entirely different. I'm Sorry for any misunderstanding caused.

Comment: @Jayadev Hi, were you able to save the canvas to svg? If so is there any place i can see the sample code on how you did that?

Comment: @AmalanDhananjayan Hi, I was unable figure out a way to do it.

Comment: @Jayadev I found a way, I'll write a blog on it and share you the link soon :)

Comment: @AmalanDhananjayan That would be really great :) Thank you!

Comment: Here is the [link to the post](https://pathofacoder.com/2016/04/20/pocket-signature-view-for-android/)

Comment: @Jayadev sir Hi, were you able to save the canvas to svg? have you write any blog?